# Is box in so-called "Kid's Box Quiz" refer to the thing pointed out by red arrow?

Tags: meaning

This is so-called Kid's Box Quiz.

[image]

Is box refer to the thing pointed out by red arrow?

related [link](http://f.eba.gov.tr/ing-soru-bankasi/cambridge/Kid-s-Box-2nd-edition-4/69455/index.html#/book/pupil/pag/6d217111a70572708230c9fef178e62a)

Comment: No, the original game had a small tin box containing cards with the questions and answers on them. Go here: https://cf.geekdo-images.com/itemrep/img/9Ls3wBVkce-isoGzcH5YM9FOu_k=/fit-in/246x300/pic3857084.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - the item you are pointing at is a *podium*, or a *rostrum*.

'*Kid's Box*' is apparently the copyrighted name used on learning material for young children produced by Cambridge University Press. The covers of such materials variously depict a box, like a toy box, full of activities for children.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very helpful. How to determine that 'Kid's Box' is apparently the copyrighted name? I googled "Kid's Box" "copyright" and got this "The authors and publishers acknowledge the following sources of copyright". I didn't see somewhere explicitly claim that copyright. I am willing to create another post if needed.

Comment: @peterpanai I think it is easier for native speakers to pick up on unfamiliar proper nouns, because if something does not make gramatical sense or is not an idiomatic phrase it is often a safe assumption that it is a noun.